# I want to extend a session timeout but phpinfo doesn't recognise it

Tags: php

I want to extend my $_SESSION variables in my php to 50 minutes but when I try to change it, in my phpinfo() command it doesn't seem to change the expire time for the session. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to be able to extend a session?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
  // PHP code
  session_start(); 
  phpinfo();

  ini_set(’session.gc_maxlifetime’, 50*60);
  ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’,50);
ini_set(‘session.gc_probability’,1);
ini_set(‘session.gc_divisor’,1);

?>
```

Below is what it currently say for SESSION in phpinfo() command:

```
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to set that variables **before** your `phpinfo()` and `session_start()`, because GC works right in the `session_start()` call and after that those parameters don't make sense
2. You also need to put the sessions with different lifetime in different directories. Otherwise the GC with least timeout will clean up everything

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. All the sessions will have the same lifetime so it will be ok :)

Comment: @user1653070: all the sessions for the whole server? If so - why wouldn't you change that in `php.ini`?

Comment: Hi, I want to know that if you have time if you can look at an old stackoverflow question I posted 9 hours ago? Its a good question but can't seem to understand what needs to be done to solve it: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374377/when-i-include-a-javascript-function-it-stops-adding-a-number-in-my-php)

Comment: Can I ask how I can access the php.ini file?

Comment: @user1653070: uhm, is it your server? If it's a shared hosting - then likely you cannot, but to be sure you need to contact support or browse their FAQ

Comment: It is a university server. Im guessing I have to ask an admin to do it for me? Or shall I just do what I am doing now and set the session's maxlifetime?

Comment: @user1653070: as I proposed - to 100% exclude all probable issues caused by server settings additionally specify your own directory for storing session files using `session.save_path` directive. And also keep in mind, that you need to specify new lifetime and new path for your **EVERY** script that uses sessions.